# Do i require to Submit a verfication request for the following google drive scopes in order to download a file from picker?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, drive

Do i require to Submit a verification request for the following google drive scopes in order to download a file from picker?

- googleapis.com/auth/drive
- www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly

The picker doesn't load due to the following error

[image: Error: invalid_sope]

My objective is to download a file from google drive to our website.

The picker loads when i use drive.file, but when i try to download the file i get a 404 file not found error.

using the google drive reference files/get on there site i can simulate the 404 but if i change the scope to using just drive or drive.readonly i get a 200 status which is what i'm after but the picker does not load.

Is there a way around this without having to submit a verification request form?

The code i'm using is based of google drive sample code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Picker Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var developerKey = '';

      // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
      var clientId = ""

      // Scope to use to access user's photos.
      var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

      var pickerApiLoaded = false;
      var oauthToken;

      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
        gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
      }

      function onAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
              'client_id': clientId,
              'scope': scope,
              'immediate': false
            },
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      function onPickerApiLoad() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
        createPicker();
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
          createPicker();
        }
      }

      // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
      function createPicker() {
     var view = new google.picker.DocsView();
     view.setIncludeFolders(true);
        
        if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
          var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
              addView(view).
              setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
              setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
              setCallback(pickerCallback).
              build();
          picker.setVisible(true);
        }
      }

      // A simple callback implementation.
      function pickerCallback(data) {
        debugger;
        var url = 'nothing';
        var id = "";
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
          id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        }
        
        
        var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + id + "?alt=media";
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken); 
    
    xhr.send();
    
        
        //var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
        //document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
      }
      
      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the scope in the variable picker

```
      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
          addView(view).
          addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).//<== add this
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i did this and it worked well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest using the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive to have full scope. Then, show us what the code, how are you doing it?

Comment: Thanks @Danee, I have edited my post to show the sample code i'm using. I have tried it with full scope and i get the same issue as mentioned.